# Unknown flower in Belarus

Tags: identification, flowers

What is this flower? My mother grows it in her garden. We live in Belarus and the flower was found here. Sorry for bad quality.
[image]
[image]

Comment: More detail would be good, like how tall and wide is the plant - a picture of the whole plant too if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Shoofly Plant (Nicandra physalodes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicandra).

"Nicandra is a monotypic genus of flowering plants in the nightshade family containing the single species Nicandra physalodes. It is known by the common names apple-of-Peru and shoo-fly plant. It is native to Peru, and it is known elsewhere as an introduced species and sometimes a weed. It is also kept as an ornamental plant."

"[Plants of Belarus](http://hbc.bas-net.by/plantae/eng/plantinfo.php?kodnazv=6479&aaafamilia=eNortjI0sFIKzs9JzEtMTk1MVbIGXDA0pgW0&genus=eNortrKwUvLLTE7MSylKVLIGXDAlbAS_&species=eNortjI0sFIqyKgsTszJT0ktVrIGXDA3OwYE&aut_sp=eNortjI0slLS8NHTVHBPTC0qydNTsgZcMDTyBUQ,&intrasp=&type=ras)" has a link to a PDF in Russian describing it with specifics to your region.

[image]